# Combining 2 columns to make one Pandas Datetime

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
             date   time  col3
0  7/18/2016 0:00  01:00     1
1  7/21/2016 0:00  01:11     4
2  7/31/2016 0:00  01:31     6
```

I want to combine the date and time columns to use as the index. I am having difficulties doing this due to the date column having the '0:00' time in for all of the dates.

Is there a way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like so:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.date + ' ' + df.time), inplace=True)
```

If you want to drop `'date'` and `'time'` columns afterwards, you can do it like so:

```
df.drop(['date','time'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```